# How to substitute some vowels with corresponding number representation using sed or awk?

Tags: regex, sed, awk

Having a file with multiple (millions) email addresses, is it possible to apply this conversion

```
a->4, e->3, i->1, o->0
```

for all email addresses present? So that for instance

`test@example.com` gets replaced with `t3st@3x4mpl3.c0m` ?

I have given it a lot of time and effort but find it impossible to accomplish with my sed and regex skills.
It's not a school exercise, it's just a privacy concern when opensourcing software.

Imagine the data is a log file with millions of email addreses.

Comment: BTW, if you are really worried about privacy then the mechanism that you are thinking of is rather easy to reverse.

Comment: Does this file have other stuff than email, that do not need to be converted? Or only emails?

Comment: I'll do the same with consonants then

Comment: @Jotne, yes, it's a log file from syslog

Comment: Updated my post to only change email and not other stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
cat file
this is a test here is an email my.test@email.com not this
Here are two email my@post.com and not.my@gmail.org
None here
```

Then with `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./ && $i~"@") {gsub(/a/,"4",$i);gsub(/e/,"3",$i);gsub(/i/,"1",$i);gsub(/o/,"0",$i)}}1'
this is a test here is an email my.t3st@3m41l.c0m not this
Here are two email my@p0st.c0m and n0t.my@gm41l.0rg
None here
```

How does it work:

```
awk '
    {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # Loop trough all fields in the string
        if ($i~/\./ && $i~"@") {    # If sting a field contains "." and "@" assume email
            gsub(/a/,"4",$i)        # Change the letter for the field
            gsub(/e/,"3",$i)        # Change the letter for the field
            gsub(/i/,"1",$i)        # Change the letter for the field
            gsub(/o/,"0",$i)        # Change the letter for the field
            }
    }1' file                        # Read the input file
```

Comment: Fantastic Jotne, you saved me hours of time, it is not so easy as it may seem, thank you

Comment: @Sloin You are welcome. Updated post with some info on how it works.  You can expand this to any letter you like.

Comment: just one last think, would you be willing to do the same for email occurrences that are not delimited by space like  'attribute=<test@example.com>' ? I don't think it can be done using this NF loop right ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) command instead:

```
$ tr 'aeio' '4310' <<< "test@example.com"
t3st@3x4mpl3.c0m
```

As `devnull` pointed out, if the data is in a file, you can do

```
tr 'aeio' '4310' < myfile
```

Comment: what is that `tr` ?  and `<<<` ?

Comment: Well I guess that you can't do that in a file for all email addresses present using 'tr'

Comment: @aelor tr is a utility for replacing characters. The `<<<` syntax means that the standard input of the command comes from the string following the `<<<`

Comment: @Sloin if you can take one input you obviously can take a file of inputs. and if you are so much tensed, use while read line

Comment: @user000001 You'll soon realize that it's often fun to be able to see deleted posts.

Comment: sorry guys for not asking the question properly, the data is a syslog log file

Comment: @Sloin Unfortunately `tr` does not have a `-i` option for inline editing like `sed` does. But you can overcome this with `tr ... < logfile >tmp && cat tmp > logfile. This will keep the permissions of the logfile intact

Comment: I really don't think you can do what Jotne put up together with awk, thank you though for helping user000001

Answer (score 2):

Extending [user000001's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575713/970195) solution with `bash` to only modify email addresses:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -ra words; do
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do
        if [[ $word =~ ^.+@.*$ ]]; then
            modwords+=( $(tr 'aeio' '4310' <<< $word) )
        else 
            modwords+=( $word )
        fi
    done 
    echo "${modwords[@]}"
    modwords=()
done < inputFile
```

**Output:**

```
this is a test here is an email my.t3st@3m41l.c0m not this
Here are two email my@p0st.c0m and n0t.my@gm41l.0rg
None here
```

You can redirect the output to another file or do `< inputFile > tmp && mv tmp inputFile`.

Comment: +1, but `[[ $word =~ @ ]]` (the regex is not anchored, so no need for `.*`) or even `[[ $word = *@* ]]` would suffice, the latter probably being a bit faster as well.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianFrühwirth, good point. Though it might update a twitter handle. `:)`. How about `^.+@.*$`?

Comment: Agreed, but then I'd at least use `^.+@.+[.].+$` to make sure there's a `domain.tld` part :) It should be noted though that matching email addresses with a regex is usually not a good idea since an RFC-compliant regex is *huge* which results in many websites being way too strict with their stupid validators :(

Comment: True. Using a full blown language like perl would be better using one their email parsing modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'y/aeio/4310/' YourFile
```

Tr will be much faster but if you only have sed ...